# Where does the equivalent friction act on a block sliding on an incline?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, friction

If a block is sliding down an incline it means the Normal force is acting at a point $x$ distance from the middle of the bottom of the base to produce an anti-torque to keep the body in rotational equilibrium. Now my question is will kinetic friction act at the point normal acts, or at the far end of the block? And whichever it is, why so?

Answer (score 1):

Kinetic friction acts at **every point of the block**, and so does the normal force. The offset location of the normal force is just a way of sidestepping the summing the torque of normal forces acting at every point. This is similar to defining the [*center of mass*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass), which is the point where all the mass can be assumed to be concentrated (not always, though). In a similar way, the distance of the offset normal force is just an *average of the location* of all the normal forces such that the net result of all the normal forces can be equivalently expressed by the new singular force acting at a specific location.

So, the normal force, and the friction act at all the point of the block (which are in contact with the inclined plane), however, their magnitude at all the locations is not uniform and thus ther is a net torque generated due to the normal force. If the normal forces had been uniformly distributed, then their torques would cancel each other out, which is the case when the *equivalent* normal force passes through the center of mass.

Finding the equivalent point is quite simple, you just need to find a point, where if all the force was applied, the same torque would be generated as in the case of spread out normal forces. Mathematicaly, if we assume the point below the center of mass and lying onthe inclined plane as our origin, then $$x_0=\frac{\displaystyle\int_{-a}^b x\:\mathrm  dN}{N_{\text{total}}}$$ where $x_0$ is the distance of the equivalent point, $a$ is the length of the surface of contact on one side of the origin, and $b$ on the other, $N_{\text{total}}$ is the total normal force, $\mathrm d N$ is the normal force applied by the inclined on the body at a distance $x$.

Comment: Okay, I believe I have gained some clarity. But I think this simply changes my question to where does the average or equivalent frictional force act then?

Comment: @l1mbo See my edit.